# How to add beats per-minute calculator to a Processing code?

Tags: java

I am using a code I got from a site for a heartbeat sensor. The signal, when displayed by this code looks something like this:

[image]

Could you help me add a check which will increment an integer every time a signal goes above a certain threshold? This needs to happen for 10 seconds only, after 10 seconds the check stops and then gets multiplied by 6 to display the amount of beats per minute.

The code I'm using gets the imaging done, I would like to add the beats per minute onto it.

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort; // The serial port
int xPos = 1; // horizontal position of the graph
float oldHeartrateHeight = 0; // for storing the previous reading

void setup () {
  // set the window size:
  size(600, 400);
  frameRate(25);

  // List available serial ports.
  println(Serial.list());

  // Setup which serial port to use.
  // This line might change for different computers.
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);

  // set inital background:
  background(0);
}

void draw () {
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  // read the string from the serial port.
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');

  if (inString != null) {
    // trim off any whitespace:
    inString = trim(inString);
    // convert to an int
    println(inString);
    int currentHeartrate = int(inString);

    // draw the Heartrate BPM Graph.
    float heartrateHeight = map(currentHeartrate, 0, 1023, 0, height);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    line(xPos - 1, height - oldHeartrateHeight, xPos, height - heartrateHeight);
    oldHeartrateHeight = heartrateHeight;
    // at the edge of the screen, go back to the beginning:
    if (xPos >= width) {
      xPos = 0;
      background(0);
    } else {
      // increment the horizontal position:
      xPos++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What sort of range does the value have? Assuming it swings above and below 0 then a simple check would be look out for whenever your value goes from negative to positive; i.e. something like `currentHeartrate>=0` and `oldHeartrateHeight<0`. This doesn't account for signal noise though.

Comment: The range of the signal is from about 600 to 900 units, each of which represent a voltage in a circuit.

Comment: In which case, swap 0 for the midpoint (so 750 there) and apply it to a moving average to account for signal noise. Assuming it's critical software, i.e. for actually monitoring a heart, I'm not very keen to post code as an answer :)

Comment: I have very little programming experience. This is an engineering side project, not really medical or critical in any way. BPM display is also just something i would like to add for ease of use. I planned to use the sensor as a display piece at home so i guessed having an average BPM to having just a visual indicator would be a little more polished. Is there any way you can help me out with it?

Comment: If you found that answer useful it would be great if you could upvote/accept/both it so others are aware.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Of course, it goes without saying, this is only a guideline. Don't hook it up to someone's heart without thorough testing!*

The simplest of checks is to look out for whenever the signal crosses a virtual line - typically the midpoint, like so:

[image: Crossover points are easier]

That immediately makes things easier - we just need to check when our latest value is above the line, and the previous one is below it; whenever that happens, our signal must've crossed the line. That's as simple as this, using `750` as your midpoint:

```
int currentHeartrate = int(inString);
int midpoint=750;

if(currentHeartrate >= midpoint && oldHeartrateHeight < midpoint){

    // It crossed the line!
    beats++;

}
```

Looking closer at your signal, it's really noisy, which means we might get pretty unlucky with a sample which goes above the line then immediately drops below it giving us a false reading. To deal with that, you could add a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) to your currentHeartrate value - that'll smooth out the fine noise for you. Add this to your project:

```
public class MovingAverage {

    private final float[] window;
    private float sum = 0f;
    private int fill;
    private int position;


    public MovingAverage(int size) {
        this.window=new float[size];
    }

    public void add(float number) {

        if(fill==window.length){
            sum-=window[position];
        }else{
            fill++;
        }

        sum+=number;
        window[position++]=number;

        if(position == window.length){
            position=0;
        }

    }

    public float getAverage() {
        return sum / fill;
    }

}
```

Rather than using `currentHeartrate` and `oldHeartrateHeight`, you'd instead first obtain the moving average - let's call it `averageHeartrate` - then cache that in `oldAverageHeartrate` and perform the same comparison with these two values instead.

Taking this a little further, you could make your BPM indicator realtime by *counting the number of samples between these beat marks*. As you've got a fixed number of samples per second, you then divide those and apply another moving average to this time reading. That then gives us this:

```
public int samplesSinceBeat; // Tracks the # of samples since the prev beat
public float oldAverageHeartrate; // Renamed
public int samplesPerSecond=10000; // However many samples/sec
public float midpoint=750; // The midpoint
public MovingAverage averageSamples=new MovingAverage(10); // Averaging over 10 samples
public MovingAverage beatTimeAverage=new MovingAverage(4); // Averaging over 4 beats

..

int currentHeartrate = int(inString);

// Add to your moving average buffer:
averageSamples.add(currentHeartrate);

float averageHeartrate=averageSamples.getAverage();

// Bump up the number of samples since the last beat:
samplesSinceBeat++;

if(averageHeartrate >= midpoint && oldAverageHeartrate < midpoint){

    // It crossed the line - we have a beat!

    // The time since the last beat is therefore:
    float timeBetweenBeats=(float)samplesSinceBeat / (float)samplesPerSecond;

    // Add time between beats to another moving average:
    beatTimeAverage.add(timeBetweenBeats);

    // Reset samples since beat:
    samplesSinceBeat=0;

}

oldAverageHeartrate=averageHeartrate;

// The BPM is now this:
int realtimeBPM= (int)(60f / beatTimeAverage.getAverage() );
```

*Some signals are evil* and have a moving midpoint too. If this is the case, I would approach that by recording:

- The largest value seen since the previous beat
- The smallest value seen since the previous beat

Then simply take the midpoint from those. Essentially, you'd end up tracking the midpoint as you go:

```
if( currentHeartrate > maxHeartrateValue){
  maxHeartrateValue=currentHeartrate;
}

if( currentHeartrate < minHeartrateValue){
  minHeartrateValue=currentHeartrate;
}

// This line is unchanged:
if(averageHeartrate >= midpoint && oldAverageHeartrate < midpoint){

    // It crossed the line - we have a beat!
    midpoint=(minHeartrateValue + maxHeartrateValue) / 2;

    // Clear!
    minHeartrateValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    maxHeartrateValue=Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    ..
```

Comment: I will look into it although I think I probably don't have enough knowledge on how to implement the code anyway. If i changed the sampling rate i could cut down on the noise, it really wouldn't be a big deal I imagine. Then i wouldn't have the need for the moving average. Then I could use it for the normal 10 second period and multiply by 6 for BPM. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: @Oppogo You'd either have to introduce a timer or count the samples until you've seen 10 seconds worth - this is also counting samples but using it in a slightly different way to give realtime results. I'll drop in a couple more parts though :)